# what is .on("click.stupidtable") in a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does `click.stupidtable` means here : `$table.on("click.stupidtable")` ?

And `$(this).stupidsort()` : I thought `$(this)` would refer to the `$table` element, so the element on which the plugin was called, but then it calls `stupidsort()`, so I am a bit confused :

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.stupidtable = function(sortFns) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $table = $(this);
      sortFns = sortFns || {};
      sortFns = $.extend({}, $.fn.stupidtable.default_sort_fns, sortFns);
      $table.data('sortFns', sortFns);

      $table.on("click.stupidtable", "thead th", function() {
          $(this).stupidsort();
      });
    });
  };


  // Expects $("#mytable").stupidtable() to have already been called.
  // Call on a table header.
  $.fn.stupidsort = function(force_direction){
```

Comment: `.on("click.stupidtable")` is binding a `click` event on `$table` on the namespace `.stupidtable`. You can then remove all events under that namespac with `$table.off('.stupidtable')`

Comment: `$(this).stupidsort()` is calling `$.fn.stupidsort` and setting the context to `this` which is the table's DOM node.

Comment: @dev-null yes thanks for the second point, I mixed it up in my mind. Ok for the first point, didn't know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does click.stupidtable means here : `$table.on("click.stupidtable")` ?

It's hooking up a *namespaced* event handler; see [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for details. This makes it easier to remove the handler later, without disturbing other `click` handlers that may be attached.

E.g., consider:

```
$("div").on("click", function() { alert("1"); });
$("div").on("click.foo", function() { alert("2"); });
```

If we click any div that existed when they ran, we'll see both alerts. Then we can use the namespace to unhook only the second one:

```
$("div").off("click.foo");
```

Now we'd only see the `1` alert.

> And `$(this).stupidsort()` : I thought `$(this)` would refer to the `$table` element...

No, in that code `this` refers to a `th` element, so `$(this)` creates a jQuery wrapper around the `th`. Note that that line is **inside** this event handler:

```
$table.on("click.stupidtable", "thead th", function() {
    $(this).stupidsort();
});
```

Since the event handler is delegated (see `on` for details on that too), in the callback, `this` will refer to the `th` element that was clicked.

> so the element on which the plugin was called, but then it calls stupidsort(), so I am a bit confused

`stupidsort` is a plugin, defined later in the code; `$(this).stupidsort()` is just calling the plugin, using the jQuery wrapper around the `th` that was clicked.

Comment: ok thanks I didn't know about namespaces. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Paul: I just noticed that the `$(this).stupidsort()` you referred to is inside an event handler, so I fixed the second part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

JS events can be namespaced, so it means, that u assign namespaced click event (namespace: stupidtable).

Comment: *"JS events can be namespaced"* JavaScript doesn't have events. DOM events cannot be namespaced. *jQuery* provides an infrastructure on top of DOM events that includes the namespacing feature.